# ezANOVA R check error normally distributed

Tags: r, anova

I am using ezANOVA to implement the analysis of an experimental design having a within subject variable and a between subject variable. I successfully implemented ezANOVA as follows:

```
structure(list(Sub = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A7011", "A7022", "B13", "B14"
), class = "factor"), Depvariable = c(0.375, 0.066667, 0.15, 
0.275, 0.025, 0.78333, 0.24167, 0.058333, 0.14167, 0.19167, 0.5, 
0), Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), WithinFactor = c(0.6, 
0, -0.3, 0.6, 0, -0.3, 0.6, 0, -0.3, 0.6, 0, -0.3)), .Names = c("Sub", 
"Depvariable", "Group", "WithinFactor"), row.names = c(NA, 12L
 ), class = "data.frame")


mod.ez<-ezANOVA(data,
          dv = .(Depvariable),
          wid = .(Sub),  # subject
          within = .(WithinFactor),  
          between=.(Group),
          type=3, 
          detailed=TRUE,
          return_aov=TRUE)
```

I am stuck with the procedure to check normal distribution of the residuals. 
I've tried the following:

```
shapiro.test(as.numeric(residuals(mod.ez$aov)))
```

But I get the following error

Error in shapiro.test(as.numeric(residuals(mod.ez$aov))) : 
  sample size must be between 3 and 5000

If I call `residuals(mod.ez$aov)` the result is NULL.

I alternatively used lmer where check of the residuals seem straighforward

```
plot(fitted(model_lmer), residuals(model_lmer))
```

However, as ezANOVA also has implemented sphericity's tests and corrections I would like to stick to it and find a way of check assumption re normality of the residuals.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: any chance for a small reproducible example?

Comment: Checking [code on GitHub](https://github.com/mike-lawrence/ez), I don't see how one could get what you want out of the box. Functions don't return anything other than some "limited" output. There is a `return_models` for `ezMixed`, but that's just formula models (which could be used to construct models "manually").

Comment: could something like `r = unlist(sapply(1:4, function(x) get("residuals",mod.ez$aov[[x]])))` and `shapiro.test(r)` be useful?

Comment: Thank you @seth, your solution does not work unfortunately...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In steps:

**Full example**

First, a full version of your code is:

```
library(ez)

data <- structure(list(Sub = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A7011", "A7022", "B13", "B14"
), class = "factor"), Depvariable = c(0.375, 0.066667, 0.15, 
0.275, 0.025, 0.78333, 0.24167, 0.058333, 0.14167, 0.19167, 0.5, 
0), Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), WithinFactor = c(0.6, 
0, -0.3, 0.6, 0, -0.3, 0.6, 0, -0.3, 0.6, 0, -0.3)), .Names = c("Sub", 
"Depvariable", "Group", "WithinFactor"), row.names = c(NA, 12L
 ), class = "data.frame")

mod.ez <- ezANOVA(
    data,
    dv = .(Depvariable),
    wid = .(Sub),  # subject
    within = .(WithinFactor),  
    between = .(Group),
    type = 3, 
    detailed = TRUE,
    return_aov = TRUE)
```

**How to explore complicated R structures**

Second, if you can't find residuals (etc.), a question is: does the result of ezANOVA actually contain them, or has it chucked out the info? For this sort of question, I like to use this function:

```
wtf_is <- function(x) {
    # For when you have no idea what something is.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589
    cat("1. typeof():\n")
    print(typeof(x))
    cat("\n2. class():\n")
    print(class(x))
    cat("\n3. mode():\n")
    print(mode(x))
    cat("\n4. names():\n")
    print(names(x))
    cat("\n5. slotNames():\n")
    print(slotNames(x))
    cat("\n6. attributes():\n")
    print(attributes(x))
    cat("\n7. str():\n")
    print(str(x))
}
```

Thus:

```
wtf_is(mod.ez)
```

**Hunting for residuals in ezANOVA output**

The output is long. We're looking for lists of length 12 (since you have 12 data points), or things looking like residuals or predicted values. Part of the output is:

```
[...]
7. str():
List of 2
 $ ANOVA:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  9 variables:
 [...]
 $ aov  :List of 4
  ..$ (Intercept)     :List of 9
  [...]
  ..$ Sub             :List of 9
  [...]
  .. ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:3] 0.102 -0.116 0.164
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "2" "3" "4"
  [...]
  .. ..$ fitted.values: Named num [1:3] -1.39e-17 1.28e-01 9.03e-02
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "2" "3" "4"
  ..$ Sub:WithinFactor:List of 9
  [...]
  .. ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:4] 0.00964 0.00964 0.23081 -0.23081
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "5" "6" "7" "8"
  [...]
  .. ..$ fitted.values: Named num [1:4] 0.0804 -0.0804 -0.0444 -0.0444
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "5" "6" "7" "8"
  [...]
  ..$ Within          :List of 6
  [...]
  .. ..$ residuals    : num [1:4, 1] 0.3286 0.1098 -0.4969 0.0564
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "9" "10" "11" "12"
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ fitted.values: num [1:4, 1] 0 0 0 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "9" "10" "11" "12"
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  [...]
  ..- attr(*, "error.qr")=List of 5
  .. ..$ qr   : num [1:12, 1:8] -3.464 0.289 0.289 0.289 0.289 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "(Intercept)" "Sub1" "Sub2" "Sub3" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:8] 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "contrasts")=List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ Sub: chr "contr.helmert"
  [...]
```

... none of which looks very helpful to me. So the answer is probably "it's not there", or "not obviously there", and others agree: [ggplot2 residuals with ezANOVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238213/ggplot2-residuals-with-ezanova)

**Using afex::aov_ez instead**

So you could instead use:

```
library(afex)
model2 <- aov_ez(
    id = "Sub",  # subject
    dv = "Depvariable",
    data = data,
    between = c("Group"),
    within = c("WithinFactor"),
    type = "III"  # or 3; type III sums of squares
)
anova(model2)
summary(model2)
residuals(model2$lm)
```

... and that does give you residuals.

However, it also gives different `F`/`p` values.

**Noting why aov_ez and ezANOVA are giving different answers here**

We have:

```
> mod.ez
$ANOVA
              Effect DFn DFd         SSn        SSd          F         p p<.05         ges
1              Group   1   2 0.024449088 0.05070517 0.96436277 0.4296328       0.134418588
2       WithinFactor   1   2 0.001296481 0.10673345 0.02429382 0.8904503       0.008167579
3 Group:WithinFactor   1   2 0.015557350 0.10673345 0.29151781 0.6433264       0.089928978

> anova(model2)
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: Depvariable
                   num Df den Df      MSE      F     ges Pr(>F)
Group              1.0000 2.0000 0.025353 0.9644 0.07197 0.4296
WithinFactor       1.4681 2.9363 0.090093 0.2322 0.08876 0.7471
Group:WithinFactor 1.4681 2.9363 0.090093 1.5001 0.38628 0.3370
```

Different results. Notice the warning message from mod.ez:

```
Warning: "WithinFactor" will be treated as numeric
```

... i.e. as a continuous predictor (covariate), not a discrete predictor (factor). So we should look at the `covariate` and `factorize` arguments; see `?aov_ez`. I must say that I struggled a bit to work out how to do a within-subjects ANCOVA here. The `factorize` part applies only to between-subjects predictors, if I read the docs correctly, and similarly `covariate` is for between-subjects covariates only.

As a quick check, if you use ezANOVA and force it to use WithinFactor as a discrete (not continuous) predictor, like this:

```
data$WithinCovariate <- data$WithinFactor  # so the name is clearer!
data$WithinFactorDiscrete <- as.factor(data$WithinFactor)
mod.ez.discrete <- ezANOVA(
    data,
    dv = .(Depvariable),
    wid = .(Sub),  # subject
    within = .(WithinFactorDiscrete),  
    between = .(Group),
    type = 3, 
    detailed = TRUE,
    return_aov = TRUE)
```

... you get `F`/`p` values that match `aov_ez`:

```
> mod.ez.discrete
$ANOVA
                      Effect DFn DFd        SSn        SSd          F          p p<.05        ges
1                (Intercept)   1   2 0.65723113 0.05070517 25.9236350 0.03647725     * 0.67583504
2                      Group   1   2 0.02444909 0.05070517  0.9643628 0.42963280       0.07197457
3       WithinFactorDiscrete   2   4 0.03070651 0.26453641  0.2321534 0.80280844       0.08876045
4 Group:WithinFactorDiscrete   2   4 0.19841198 0.26453641  1.5000731 0.32651697       0.38627588
```

So that gets you matching results, and Greenhouse-Geisser/Huynh-Feldt corrections, and residuals, for everything except within-subjects covariates.

**Finally...**

What does it mean to check sphericity with a continuous within-subjects predictor? I am entirely unclear on that; sphericity relates to homogeneity of variance of the differences between pairs of values at various levels of the within-subjects factor(s). If the predictor is continuous, there are no pairs.

So at the risk of being wrong, I would either
(a) trust ezANOVA and forgo residuals;
(b) use something that can do everything except the sphericity tests, like this:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)  # upgrades reports from lme4 to include p values! ;)

mod.lmer.wscov_interact <- lmer(
    Depvariable ~
        Group * WithinCovariate
        + (1 | Sub),
    data = data
)
anova(mod.lmer.wscov_interact)
residuals(mod.lmer.wscov_interact)

mod.lmer.wscov_no_interact <- lmer(
    Depvariable ~
        Group + WithinCovariate
        + (1 | Sub),
    data = data
)
anova(mod.lmer.wscov_no_interact)

mod.lmer.wsfac <- lmer(
    Depvariable ~
        Group * WithinFactorDiscrete
        + (1 | Sub),
    data = data
)
anova(mod.lmer.wsfac)
```

giving

```
> anova(mod.lmer.wscov_interact)
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
                        Sum Sq  Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
Group                 0.033586 0.033586     1     8 0.50936 0.4957
WithinCovariate       0.001296 0.001296     1     8 0.01966 0.8920
Group:WithinCovariate 0.015557 0.015557     1     8 0.23594 0.6402

> residuals(mod.lmer.wscov_interact)
           1            2            3            4            5            6            7            8            9           10           11           12 
 0.130059250 -0.219344250 -0.156546500  0.030059250 -0.261011250  0.476783500 -0.009225679 -0.118156464  0.002383643 -0.059225679  0.323510536 -0.139286357 

> anova(mod.lmer.wscov_no_interact)
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
                   Sum Sq   Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
Group           0.0244491 0.0244491     1     9 0.40519 0.5403
WithinCovariate 0.0012965 0.0012965     1     9 0.02149 0.8867

> anova(mod.lmer.wsfac)
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
                             Sum Sq  Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
Group                      0.024449 0.024449     1     6 0.46534 0.5206
WithinFactorDiscrete       0.030707 0.015353     2     6 0.29222 0.7567
Group:WithinFactorDiscrete 0.198412 0.099206     2     6 1.88819 0.2312
```